# How to know your current user in Linux without 'whoami'

Tags: linux

just wondering, if there is a way to know which user i'm using in linux, without using 'whoami' command in terminal. May be there is a way to know it from a file? Some file where the current username is stored or something?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `/etc/passwd` (search for `$UID`).

Comment: That assumes you're using that as your user database and not LDAP.  That's not always a safe assumption.

Comment: `echo USER=$USER` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The scenic route:

The [id](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/id.1.html) command can display user information, but when called without arguments it also includes all your groups, so you'll have to massage the output a bit.

```
id
uid=501(robert) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone)...
```

First, use [cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) to pick up only the user ID part:

```
id | cut -d " " -f 1
uid=501(robert)
```

Then send that through another `cut` to remove the leading `uid=` part:

```
id | cut -d " " -f 1 | cut -c 5-
501(robert)
```

Finally, use [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to remove all characters that are not letters:

```
id | cut -d " " -f 1 | cut -c 5- | sed -E 's/[^a-zA-Z]*//'g
robert
```

The quick route, as user2394284 mentioned:

```
id --user --name
```

Guess I should actually read the man pages I link to.

Comment: Id can print only the username like this: `id --user --name`

Answer (score 1):

environment variables USER and/or LOGNAME are usually set up for your convenience.

```
$ echo $USER
bineinfachvorbeigekommen
$ echo $LOGNAME
bineinfachvorbeigekommen
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can't be *certain* that a process is associated with a user name. The best you can be sure of is that it has a numerical user ID. In fact, it will have two numeric user IDs -- the "real user ID" and the "effective user ID". Normally these are the same.

These user IDs are exposed by the kernel -- there is a kernel system call that retrieves them, and wrappers for that system call in most programming languages (e.g., `getuid()` in C).

User *name*, however, is not an intrinsic property of the process, and there's no knock-down certain way to find it from within an application. In fact, it's possible to run a process under a (numerical) user ID that has no corresponding name -- this is something that won't normally happen in desktop Linux, but is relatively normal in embedded and container systems.

User names are stored in some authentication database, like `/etc/passwd`, and can be determined from the user ID -- usually. Most Linux shells set environment variables like `$LOGNAME` and `$USER` to make life a bit easier for programmers. Utilities like `whoami` will use various methods to map the numeric user ID to a name, but this won't be foolproof, for reasons explained above.